# send arabic words with http request GET android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i Want to send arabic (unicode) with the HTTP Request

When using `URLEncodedUtils.format(params, HTTP.UTF_8);`
it give `paramString` this value when the words are in arabic 
"%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%B1%D9%87"

This is my code:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

Log.d("Parser" , paramString);
url += "?" + paramString;
Log.d("parser" , url);
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

The Server Code

```
function getShippingAddress($email)
   {
            $customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
            $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
            $customer->loadByEmail($email);
            $defaultShippingId = $customer->getDefaultShipping();
            $customerAddress->load($defaultShippingId); 
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["data"][0] = $customerAddress->getData('city');
            $response["data"][1] = $customerAddress-  >getData('street');
            $response["data"][2] = $customerAddress->getData('telephone');


        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        return json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: this is url encoded data representing the word `القاهره` , just like space is encoded into `%20`, what is the problem?

Comment: yes i want to send it in url as القاهره not as encoded data

Comment: maybe you want to check this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Thank you but still have the problem in decode the data

Comment: you don't have to worry about the data on the sender side, what happens on the server side? when you read this param using server side code, what is the output of Decoding this param?

Comment: i use this
  header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
in the server side to back the data decoded but it return encoded data

Comment: why don't you post the server side snippet code related to reading the params?

Comment: i write the server side code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sending parameter using POST. Sample code is here:

```
private String sendHttpPost(String url, String msg)
        throws Exception {

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(msg, "UTF-8");
    post.setEntity(stringEntity);


    return execute(post);
}
```

or try this :

```
String unicodeUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url += "?" + paramString, "UTF-8");
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(unicodeUrl);
```

**UPDATE:**

if your params ="Some_String_In_Arabic", try this code :

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
//String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

String unicodeUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url += "?" + params, "UTF-8");
Log.d("URL" , unicodeUrl);
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(unicodeUrl);

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

and use urldecode method (of PHP) in your server side to get the string back in arabic form.

Comment: my problem is in set the values to 'paramString' when i Log this String it give this value %D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%B1%D9%87
even when i log the 'params' it give the right values

Comment: It will be. you are encoding the data as valid url. You just add the unicode value to paramString, and use the second code I gave.

Or just attach the value (the %D8%A7 is an arabic character actually) and do the GET. To retreive the value at server side, use urldecode function

Comment: i added The unicode value to paramString, and still the same starng values added to url

Comment: you got the data in the server correctly? did you check that?

Comment: you cannod send unicode data as such to server. you have to encode it!

Comment: Please verify the data received is just equivalent to the sent one.

And please post the encoded data you got in server, here. Let me check it


(Then your question here is closed I think :-)  Now, decoding the data is not about android, but its in PHP :-)... Just kidding :-) )

Comment: Thank You :-) 
the data is the same but its saved in the server side encoded, although i decode it in the server side code

Comment: Give me the Server side data , adn the code you used to decode it. I will give a try

Comment: Thank you, i solved it from java code side i decode the result

Answer (score 0):

```
  static Future GetSearch(searching, language) async {
    try {
      Map<String, String> headervalue = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        //'search': Uri.encodeFull(searching),
        //'search': searching,
        'search': "${utf8.encode(searching)}",
        'language': language
      };
      var url1 = Uri.parse(
          "${BaseUrl.baseurl}/apikey");
      var response = await http.get(url1, headers: headervalue);
      print('search' + searching); // print(response.body);
      print(headervalue);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      // return onError(e, "login/Users/login");
    }
  }
```

> 'search': "${utf8.encode(searching)}",

if your are getting
Failed to read the 'headers' property from 'RequestInit': String contains non ISO-8859-1 code point.

if you are using search in multiple language if you use language other than english it gives an error of ISO so you have to encode this to client side and decode on server side to achieve the result